подключение базы данных к проекту java
как подключить бд mysql к проекту apache? скачивал коннектор 8.0.33, но что  необходимо прописать в pom.xml и вообщем сделать для подключения? коннектор скачен и находится в репозитории мавен
код в pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>company</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <exec.mainClass>com.mycompany.company.company</exec.mainClass>
    </properties> </project>


Уточните, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос.

постарался уточнить и дополнил вопрос

<dependency> должно быть внутри <dependencies>

ошибка все равно присутствует, которая на 1 скришоте

Как ты запускаешь то что на скриншоте?

по проекту->new->other->persistence->entity classes from database

удалось добавить, но теперь данная ошибка: Error: Could not find or load main class com.isp.insurancecompany.Insurancecompany
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.isp.insurancecompany.Insurancecompany

Если нет базы данных, то откуда брать таблицы? И что собственно подключать?

бд создана и таблицы добавлены все из неё, но при запуске проекта выходит ошибка, которая выше в комментариях

ошибка указывает на то, что maven не может найти или загрузить главный класс

Google говорит нужно
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.0</version>
</dependency>


да, это прописано, но добавить классы(таблицы) не выходит

Экстрасенсы не проснулись еще, нужны детали.

постарался уточнить и дополнил вопрос
